# postgresql copy from csv file into table in windows through procedure

Tags: postgresql, psql

below is my procedure executed to upload file into table and do joins etc.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sp_product_price()
    RETURNS void
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    AS $BODY$
BEGIN
    truncate table prd_product_data;
    truncate table price_import;    
    COPY price_import FROM 'C:\Users\Ram\Documents\prices.csv'  CSV HEADER; 
    truncate table active_product_price;    
    insert into active_product_price(key,name,price)
    SELECT prd.key,prd.name,prd.price FROM prd_product_data prd JOIN price_import import ON prd.name = import.name;  
    raise notice 'success';

END
$BODY$;
```

Above procedure giving error `could not open file "C:\Users\Ram\Documents\prices.csv" for reading: No such file or directory HINT:  COPY FROM instructs the PostgreSQL server process to read a file. You may want a client-side facility such as psql's \copy.`

I have given access to file for everyone in file properties.

I tried \copy in procedure but this gives error `syntax error at or near "\"` .

\copy is working when I ran cmd in psql but not in above procedure.

Is there a way to import file into table in above procedure/functions ?

Comment: You may have given the permissions to the file, but did you do the same for the  directories in the path?

Comment: The file needs to be on the C: of the database server computer, not the C: of the client computer (if those are different).

Comment: file is in C: of client and not in database server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The procedure and the `COPY` statement are running on the database server, so the file `C:\Users\Ram\Documents\prices.csv` must be on the database server as well (and your database user must either be a superuser or a member of `pg_read_server_files`).

The only way you can use `COPY` to load data from the client is `COPY ... FROM STDIN`, and you won't be able to use that in a procedure.

`\copy` is a `psql` command, not an SQL statement, so it cannot be used in a procedure either.

My suggestion is to use `\copy`, but to forget about the procedure.